# Cannot Find Symbol of Variable Address and Port

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a server that uses threads to allow multiple nodes to connect and when they connect the server receives the nodes information and stores it to a linked list. The problem I'm having is that when trying to link the nodelist.addNode line in the NodeManager class to the CreateNode class that creates a new node, it displays cannot find symbol. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Below is the client run() method:

```
 @Override
public void run() {

clientList client = new clientList();
while(true){
try {
    //byte[] buffer = new byte [256];
    in = new BufferedReader(new            InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));  
    out = new PrintWriter(this.s.getOutputStream(),);
    String string = in.toString();

    address = socket.getInetAddress();
    port = socket.getPort();
    System.out.println("address: " + address);
    System.out.println("Node Port number: " + port);

    clientlist.addNode(new Createclient(address, port));        
    System.out.println("Current clients connected: " + clientlist);
    break;       
    } catch (Exception error) {

    }
}
}
```

Below is the Create client class that creates the node:

```
public class Createclient {

private String name;
private InetAddress address;
private final int port;
private String nodeInfo;

public Createclient(InetAddress a, int p){
  address = a; port = p;
}

public InetAddress getAddress() {
   return address;
}

public int getPort() {
   return port;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
 return address + " " + port;
}
}
```

Sorry if the code is messy. I'm very new to Java and programming.

UPDATE:

The NodeList is overwriting the node that is entered into the list. When I print the list, it displays the node that has just been entered instead of adding the node to the existing list/queue.

```
public class clientList {

private String name = "client:";
private String nodeInformation;

LinkedList cleintList = new LinkedList();

public void Name(String name){
   this.name = name;
}

public void addclient (Createclient client){
  clientList.addLast(name + client.getAddress() + " : " + client.getPort());
}

 @Override      
 public String toString() {
  StringBuilder sringb = new StringBuilder();
  for(Object client clientList) {
    sringb.append(node + "\n");
   }
 return sringb.toString();
}
```

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: Which symbol can't it find, where in the code does it get this error and where do you think you did define it? From this code I can see at least 6 fields you may or may not have defined.

Comment: It says it can't find "address" and "port" in nodelist.addNode(new CreateNode(address, port)); and it has been defined in CreateNode class @PeterLawrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006221/extracting-information-from-streams-and-saving-in-linkedlist/30006371#30006371) to your previous question, you don't need to create a `NodeList` class.

So Change this

```
NodeList nodelist = new NodeList();
```

To this

```
LinkedList<CreateNode> nodelist = new LinkedList<CreateNode>();
```

Also you don't need `addNode()` method anymore so change this

```
nodelist.addNode(new CreateNode(address, port));
```

To this

```
nodelist.add(new CreateNode(nodeIP, nodePort));
```

Comment: @TNT the author has asked a question on the same topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006221/extracting-information-from-streams-and-saving-in-linkedlist/30006371#30006371). I don't know why he asks new question instead of discussing his previous one?

Comment: This has worked! Thank you. I now have another issue. When I attempt to print the list, the node overwrites the first node in the list instead of being added behind. Any ideas? @MChaker

Comment: @MChaker OP has a new issue so he asked a new question. I believe this is actually encouraged, not continuing the discussion on a previous thread.

Comment: I have edited as you have said to. Where I changed addNode to add, this now underlines 'add' saying:
cannot find symbol
symbol: method add(CreateNode)
location: variable nodelist of type NodeList. @MChaker

Comment: @JavaNovice `variable nodelist of type NodeList` so you haven't changed the type of `nodeList`. Make sure to change `NodeList nodelist = new NodeList();` to  `LinkedList<CreateNode> nodelist = new LinkedList<CreateNode>();`.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Although, every new entry to the list overwrites the current entry. Any ideas on how to fix this? @MChaker

Comment: Why have you unaccepted my answer? Is something not obvious that i can help you? @JavaNovice

Answer (score 0):

> It says it can't find "address" and "port" in nodelist.addNode(new CreateNode(address, port)); and it has been defined in CreateNode class

You defined it in CreateNode, but it has to have a value before you can pass it to the constructor.

I suspect you meant to use `nodeIP` and `NodePort` you defined on the previous lines. i.e.

```
nodelist.addNode(new CreateNode(nodeIP, nodePort));
```

either that or these variables should be renamed to match how you used them.